# Using rowSums to create a variable in R

Tags: r

I would like to capture the occurrence of a "Yes" in the desired variables.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2022)
mydata <- tibble::tibble(
  "id" = 1:100,
  "a1" = sample(c(rep("Yes", 40), rep_len(NA, 100)), 100),
  "a2" = sample(c(rep("Yes", 50), rep_len(NA, 100)), 100),
  "a3" = sample(c(rep("Yes", 40), rep_len(NA, 100)), 100),
  "a4" = sample(c(rep("Yes", 50), rep_len(NA, 100)), 100),
  "b2" = rnorm(100, 50, 10)
)

#  Goal is to capture any occurrence of Yes in  (a* variables)

anymatch <- function(vars){
  rowSums(select(cur_data(), all_of(vars))=="Yes")
}

avars <- paste0("a", 1:4)

mydata %>% 
  mutate(afin = anymatch(avars)) %>% 
  select(avars, afin)
```

Comment: It does not seem to do what is expected ...

Comment: It is getting the count of `Yes` in each row with `rowSums`.  What is your expected

Comment: The second row should have 2 because we have 2 instances of a Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `na.rm = TRUE`

```
anymatch <- function(vars){
  rowSums(select(cur_data(), all_of(vars))=="Yes", na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Now, it gives the correct count

```
>  mydata %>%
   mutate(afin = anymatch(avars)) %>% 
   select(all_of(avars), afin) 
# A tibble: 100 × 5
   a1    a2    a3    a4     afin
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      0
 2 <NA>  Yes   <NA>  Yes       2
 3 Yes   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      1
 4 <NA>  Yes   Yes   <NA>      2
 5 Yes   Yes   <NA>  <NA>      2
 6 Yes   Yes   Yes   Yes       4
 7 <NA>  Yes   <NA>  <NA>      1
 8 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      0
 9 Yes   Yes   <NA>  Yes       3
10 <NA>  Yes   <NA>  <NA>      1
# … with 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

In the future versions, we may use `pick` instead of `cur_data()`

```
anymatch <- function(vars){
   rowSums(pick(all_of(vars))=="Yes", na.rm = TRUE)
 }
mydata %>%
   mutate(afin = anymatch(avars)) %>% 
    select(all_of(avars), afin) 
# A tibble: 100 × 5
   a1    a2    a3    a4     afin
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      0
 2 <NA>  Yes   <NA>  Yes       2
 3 Yes   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      1
 4 <NA>  Yes   Yes   <NA>      2
 5 Yes   Yes   <NA>  <NA>      2
 6 Yes   Yes   Yes   Yes       4
 7 <NA>  Yes   <NA>  <NA>      1
 8 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      0
 9 Yes   Yes   <NA>  Yes       3
10 <NA>  Yes   <NA>  <NA>      1
# … with 90 more rows
```

Comment: Excellent! And how do you nicely print the output here?

Comment: @Moses Thanks.  Didn't get your comment regarding printing

Comment: The output of:

```mydata %>%
   mutate(afin = anymatch(avars)) %>% 
    select(all_of(avars), afin)
```

Comment: No @akrun. The output is exactly expected. 

I was inquiring on how to display the R output in Stackoverflow...

Comment: @Moses If you want to show a reproducible example, use `dput` i.e. `mydata %>%    mutate(afin = anymatch(avars)) %>%      select(all_of(avars), afin) %>% dput`

Comment: @Moses Other option is `reprex` package